# AS3. How to use other animation after one is complete?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, frame

I'm creating flash game and I have problem, after "Jumping" animation I need resume "Staying" animation.

I know I need to use `parent.gotoAndStop("staying");` in last frame of jumping animation. That worked before, now I changed my character added new animations and now when I try to use It I got error: `1061: Call to possibly undefined method gotoAndStop through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer.`

I've tried to use: `gotoAndStop("staying");` after this, jumping animation loop forever.
also tried `stop();` after this - animation stops in last frame, but I need to start `staying` animation. Could you help me, please? Thank you.

Comment: You should post more code or more information on where is that code located, what's accessible at the point of error and how do you refer the player MC from outside.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(player.currentFrameLabel=="jumping"){
     if(player.(getChildAt(0) as MovieClip).currentFrame==totalFrames){
         player.gotoAndStop("Staying");
     }
}
```

Edit:
I was assuming that you're using classes and not the timeline, don't use timeline, that's a terrible idea for AS3.0.

Edit2:
If you're working on the timeline, then the same thing applies, if you need to make a reference of the player like in the above code, a reference for the instance is "player".

Comment: I've used It in timeline's last frame, so where I need to use this code?

Comment: When I use It in keyDown function I got 3 errors: `1120: Access of undefined property currentFrameLabel.` other `1178: Attempted access of inaccessible property currentFrame through a reference with static type Script.` and other `1059: Property is read-only.`

Comment: @Zhafur Shouldn't work, because frame labels are assigned to one frame only, so if `currentFrameLabel == "jumping"` then there's only one frame and it's the start of the animation, not its end.

Comment: All animations loops forever, never stops till other not used. In Timline If I use this code, hero or parent instead of player I got errors 1119, 1061

Answer (score 0):

it will be at the last frame of your jumping animation

```
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop("staying");
```

The trick is simple. `parent` property inherited by `MovieClip` from `DisplayObjectContainer` and it returns reference to object as `DisplayObjectContainer`. There is no `gotoAndStop` methods defined there, so you should convert that reference to `MovieClip` to get access to it properties and methods.
The error you get (1061) said you about this.

Comment: Thank you, that half worked. Now when It is on air (jumping) and If I click left / right arrows (trying to move left or right), jumping animation canceling and character teleports to the ground. I need to make something like If character is on the air and arrows (left/right) is clicked It moved to correct side without interrupting jumping animation and without teleporting to the ground.

Comment: you should move your character left and right not by animation, but using `x` property. do you have different animation for character facing left and right?

Comment: I know, but character movement animation is for moving legs when character moving.

Comment: do he should move legs while he in jumping?